# How to fill values between some indexes in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

A 2-D tensor like:

```
[[0,0,1,0,1,0],
 [0,1,0,0,0,1]]
```

I want to fill `1` between two `1` in each row, say:

```
[[0,0,1,1,1,0],
  [0,1,1,1,1,1]]
```

What should I do with tensorflow?thx.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas for you.
Two ways to do it using naive tf-python ops or write it your own with cpp:

1.

convert your matrix to bool with `tf.cast`, then you get a bool tensor, then find the index of non-zeros elements with `tf.where` now you get an indictors tensor with shape [?, 2], for each row of this tensor(use `tf.map`), use `tf.range` to build indics where elements should be filled with one, finally you get another indictor tensor, use `tf.SparseTensor` constructor to build want you want.

2.

write an op in cpp for your self then load it into tensorflow runtime, this might be a better solution for your task but requires a little knowledge of cpp, you can go official website to see how to write an custom op, you can manipulate the underlying `Eigen::Tensor` directly so very easy to do what you want

hope can help you